# how to authenticate to REST web service from Android app?

Tags: android, authentication, rest

I need to pull data from a REST web service in my android app.  The web service requires authentication.
I need to first call a login method, which will return me an authToken and JSESSIONID as part of the response header.  I need to pass these items back with every request.  I'm currently using: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.DefaultHttpClient() to call the login method.  I can see the authToken and JSESSIONID are being returned in the response header.
Are there any existing tools or classes that might provide some sort of management functionality that I can easily integrate with my android app?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the values as key/value pairs using `SharedPreferences` and then create some kind of convenience method that appends those values to your web requests.  Once you get these values from the response store them with,

```
SharedPreferences apiVals = getSharedPreferences("apiVals", MODE_PRIVATE);
apivals.edit()
       .putString("authToken", authToken)
       .putString("jSessionId", jSessionId)
       .commit();
```

and to retrieve them,

```
SharedPreferences apiVals = getSharedPreferences("apiVals", MODE_PRIVATE);
String authToken = apiVals.getString("authToken", null);
```

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out the [SimpleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) sample project (included with Android SDK) to see how Android's account manager is used to handle authentication and credential storage.  I believe this is the way your use-case is meant to be supported in Android.